Use Merge Schema for a Delta Table used as Unity Catalog Table
Assume I have a Delta Table which I used as external table in unity catalog. Now, I have a dataframe which I would like to "append" to the unity catalog table - the schemas should be merged (auto-merge manner). How can I do that without dropping/creating the unity catalog table?

Right now I don't think there is a way to modify the metadata directly in the unity catalog. But you could try refresh table command to see if it updates the structure because all the details related to delta table is stored in the _deltalog folder and that is where it fetches the metadata information for the delta table in the catalog.
